# Is activerecord truncating timestamp precision?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4.0.0, ruby 2.0p247 with mysql2 0.3.13 gem. A column in my table in MariaDB 5.5

Note: mariadb has had microsecond precision support since 5.3

```
  `updated_at` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

The precision should be microseconds so I tried in my model file

```
before_save :set_update

def set_update
  # also tried
  # self.updated_at = "2013-10-03 12:35:00.123456 -700"  
  # self.updated_at = Time.now.strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %6N"
  # self.updated_at = Time.now.iso8601(6)
  # doesn't work, still no microseconds

  self.updated_at = Time.now.to_f
end
```

But in the database it is still

```
| updated_at                 |
+----------------------------+
| 2013-10-03 19:35:00.000000 |
+----------------------------+
```

Why is rails/activerecord not storing microseconds?

Comment: I'd guess that it is because AR is assigning values to `created_at` and `updated_at` behind your back so the database's default never gets used. Try again with a different name (and leave out the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` since AR won't understand it and will probably pretend it doesn't exist and possibly screw everything up).

Comment: @muistooshort when I hardcoded the value see (self.updated_at = "2013-10-03 12:35:00.123456 -700"), AR did use that value instead of the current time except AR truncated to ("2013-10-03 12:35:00")

Comment: AR is probably ignoring your attempts to change `updated_at` because AR knows that `updated_at` is special. Try again with a column whose name is **not** `updated_at` so that AR will get out of your way. Then, if that works, at least you know what the real problem is and you can ask "how do I keep AR's hands of my `updated_at` column?"

Comment: Another possibility is that AR thinks it knows what a timestamp is supposed to look like so it is doing a `strftime` based reformatting of the timestamp behind your back (using say `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`) and the stringification is truncating the timestamp.

Comment: tried `config.active_record.record_timestamps = false`, didn't change the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it to work:

added this to a file in config/initializers

```
class Time
  DATE_FORMATS = {
    :db => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N'
  }
end
```

see [conversions.rb](https://github.com/jgaskins/rails/blob/900dbc54f17500e14e481eab2ebf88acfc5448aa/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/conversions.rb) for more info.

Comment: Shouldn't you be modifying the dictionary/hash? E.g. `DATE_FORMATS[:db] = 'my format'`?

If I understand this correctly you will be throwing away all other formats (e.g. `:number`) from the `DATE_FORMATS`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a warning, you can update the constant rather than overwrite it. In `config/initializers/database.rb`:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!({ db: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N' })
```

You'll also need to set the precision on your database columns to > 1 second.  In a migration:

```
class IncreaseTimestampPrecision < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table_name|
      columns = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.columns(table_name)

      # set the precision to microseconds for each datetime column on the table
      columns.select {|col| col.type == :datetime }.each do |column|
        change_column table_name, column.name, :datetime, limit: 6
      end
    end
  end
end
```

end